# Simplify an expression.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, exponentiation

Don't know how to do this.

Simplify the expression, show steps:

$$\large \dfrac {a^{-\frac 14}a^{\frac 32}}{a^{\frac 13}}$$
Write the answer using only positive exponents. Assume that all variables are positive real numbers.

Comment: **Hint:** Negative power is the inverse of the positive power.

Comment: Are you familiar with http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ExponentLaws.html?

Comment: Google "negative fraction powers" and see where it will take you...

Answer (score 6):

Recall:

$$a^{-b} = \frac 1{a^b}$$

$$a^b\cdot a^c = a^{b + c}$$

$$\dfrac{a^b}{a^c} = a^{b - c}$$

See what you can do with these properties.

Comment: I like the hint approach +1